# Symfony 2: Deserialize object in twig

Tags: symfony, serialization, twig

I'm a newbie and this is my first question so please be nice with me :)

In my Symfony 2 project I want to pass an $user object from my controller to the twig template. This object contains all relevant Information (like username, activepage ...) for rendering the view. My problem is that I would also like to put the result of mysqli database query inside the object. To be able to retrieve it in my twig template, I need two serialize the result object(array?) in the controller before passing. Unfortunately I dont know a way how to deserialize that object in twig( no twig filter available).

My questions:

1. Is this actually an elegant way or should i rather pass all objects in an array to the template?
2. Would it work to write a deserialize function inside the user class, which i can call in the twig template?
3. Will performance be ok?
4. How do the experienced people do this?

Thx for helping!

Comment: If I understand you want to pass data from controller to twig and render them ?

Comment: Exactly, but i would like to concentrate all data in one object so I never have to worry about passing the correct parameters in the render call.

Comment: Is the result of your query same instance of `$user` object? I mean do you want to combine two similar objects in one?

Answer (score 0):

Built an array with your data in your controller and render it like this to your template :

```
return $this->render('yourbundle:example:index.html.twig', array(
            'myArray'   => $array,
```

Then in your template you have access to `myArray` like this :

```
{% for data in myArray %}

...

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a service such a parameter bag which I can add parameters/values along the process, and render every parameters with twig so I can use them in javascript.

For that I had to use mostly [JsonSerializable php interface](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/class.jsonserializable.php) (PHP 5.4+), and [json_decode twig filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/json_encode.html).

I think it is a nice way to pass variables to js like this because you can use this service when building your project.